# Wine: Load old Access software - Invalid ELF header

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, wine, elf

I need to run old software(Based on Access 2.00) over Wine but i have many problems.

Can someone give some pointers on this question:

```
warn:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"Z:\\home\\wellington\\.wine\\drive_c\\abc\\msarn200.exe16": /home/wellington/.wine32/dosdevices/z:/home/wellington/.wine/drive_c/abc/msarn200.exe16: cabeçalho ELF inválido
warn:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"Z:\\home\\wellington\\.wine\\drive_c\\abc\\msajt200.dll16": /home/wellington/.wine32/dosdevices/z:/home/wellington/.wine/drive_c/abc/msajt200.dll16: cabeçalho ELF inválido
warn:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"Z:\\home\\wellington\\.wine\\drive_c\\abc\\dao2016.dll16": /home/wellington/.wine32/dosdevices/z:/home/wellington/.wine/drive_c/abc/dao2016.dll16: cabeçalho ELF inválido
warn:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"Z:\\home\\wellington\\.wine\\drive_c\\abc\\msain200.dll16": /home/wellington/.wine32/dosdevices/z:/home/wellington/.wine/drive_c/abc/msain200.dll16: cabeçalho ELF inválido
warn:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"Z:\\home\\wellington\\.wine\\drive_c\\abc\\msabc200.dll16": /home/wellington/.wine32/dosdevices/z:/home/wellington/.wine/drive_c/abc/msabc200.dll16: cabeçalho ELF inválido
```

I tried do install wine with many times from different ways (  https://gist.github.com/wellington1993/8c50ca7083b3743145e51b54a44e8f00) but the problem persists.

Comment: You have some error messages, but not the command that produced them. Show us what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Access 2.0 is listed as gold app in WineHQ:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2746

The problem you are having seems to be related to the achitecture (ELF class errors). I guess you are trying to run a win32 app on a wine64 installation.

This post should guilde you through the right way to install wine for your needs:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/74690/how-to-install-32-bit-wine-on-64-bit-ubuntu#74716

Comment: I reinstalled the wine 32bit. But the problem not was solved. I think the problem is related to the architecture too. I'm curious about the 16 on "dao2016.dll16" error message.